# using Hibernate numeric restriction for a varchar column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria

I'm using the Hibernate Criteria in order to build queries dynamically.
One of these dynamic queries uses a column stored on MySQL as a varchar. But, is a column storing prices of items (only has numeric values with decimals). So I would like to generate queries using `ge` `le` or `between`.

Is there a way to tell to hibernate something like "hey, this column is of type varchar, but its content is numeric so apply my numeric restrictions (please)"?

Comment: You can not change the data type of the table?

Comment: this table is on production and I don't know if I would break something. Maybe there was a good reason to store prices as a varchars, I don't know. Anyway change data type is not an option for now.

Comment: Well, then you should declare it as String in hibernate and do the parsing in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Hibernate query is translated to SQL. If the underlying column is a varchar column I'm not sure that Hibernate can do anything about it.

As the issue is in the database tier then one suggestion would be to create a virtual column in the database (if your database supports such things) and which casts this varchar to a decimal .

Quick Google for MySql suggests:

http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/

You can then map the price field in your entity to this virtual column as a numeric type and query as required.

Failing that, you could create a 2 column view (id, price) doing something similar and map the price field to your existing Entity as a secondary table.

## Update

After checking further I note the following from the MySQL docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

> Strings are automatically converted to numbers... as necessary.

Therefore it would seem that you could do the following. Use a Type Converter (JPA 2.1) to convert between String <> Numeric type in your domain model. Given the above, simply write queries against this field using the standard numeric operators.

http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Answer (score 2):

Same problem also occured for me. My solution is that, I created a new variable of `Product` and data type is `double`. And use hibernate formula this element and than I applied `ge` , `le` and `between` to this new variable. My pojo look like this:

```
@Column
private String price;

@Formula(value="to_number(price)")
private double newDouble;
```

And my hibernate criteria look like following:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Product.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("newDouble",252.50,300));
List<Product> products = session.list();
```

I hope this will help you.